# accessing elements of a counter containing ngrams

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, n-gram

I am taking a string, tokenizing it, and want to look at the most common bigrams, here is what I have got:

```
import nltk
import collections
from nltk import ngrams

someString="this is some text. this is some more test. this is even more text."
tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(someString)
tokens=[token.lower() for token in tokens if len()>1]

bigram=ngrams(tokens,2)
aCounter=collections.Counter(bigram)
```

If I:

```
print(aCounter)
```

Then it will output the bigrams in sorted order.

```
for element in aCounter:
     print(element)
```

Will print the elements, but not with a count, and not in order of the count. I want to do a for loop, where I print out the X most common bigrams in a text.

I am essentially trying to learn both Python and nltk at the same time, so this could be why I am struggling here (I assume this is a trivial thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something that already exists, namely, the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method on counters. From the docs:

> Return a list of the `n` most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If `n` is omitted or `None`, `most_common()` returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily:

You can call it and supply a value `n` in order to get the `n` most common value-count pairs. For example:

```
from collections import Counter

# initialize with silly value.
c = Counter('aabbbccccdddeeeeefffffffghhhhiiiiiii')

# Print 4 most common values and their respective count.
for val, count in c.most_common(4):
    print("Value {0} -> Count {1}".format(val, count))
```

Which prints out:

```
Value f -> Count 7
Value i -> Count 7
Value e -> Count 5
Value h -> Count 4
```